# Where to find the liveData building block?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-coroutines

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines

Android `coroutines` plus `liveData` documentation states that we can use the `liveData` builder function in case we want to want to perform async operations inside the live data function

```
val user: LiveData<User> = liveData {
    val data = database.loadUser() // loadUser is a suspend function.
    emit(data)
}
```

```
val user: LiveData<Result> = liveData {
    emit(Result.loading())
    try {
        emit(Result.success(fetchUser())
    } catch(ioException: Exception) {
        emit(Result.error(ioException))
    }
}
```

I tried installing the `lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx` library but couldn't find this block.

Where is it located?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0-alpha01'
```

The function lives here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/lifecycle/livedata/ktx/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/CoroutineLiveData.kt

And is (currently) defined as:

```
@UseExperimental(ExperimentalTypeInference::class)
fun <T> liveData(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    timeoutInMs: Long = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
    @BuilderInference block: suspend LiveDataScope<T>.() -> Unit
): LiveData<T> = CoroutineLiveData(context, timeoutInMs, block)
```

Comment: Was looking all over the internet, finally this saved me. Why is this not on any android documentation in android.developers.com

Comment: How to subscribe to emit in Fragment?

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem, I would recommend just adding the dependencies they suggested [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#dependencies).

The issue is Google's Android docs on coroutines were not explicit in mentioning that these ktx extensions specifically (as you would see in the link) are very important to be able to get the `liveData` builder that supplies the `LiveDataScope`.

Don't make the mistake of thinking that you can just use lower versions i.e `2.1.0`, just use it as explicitly specified in the doc i.e. the alpha/RC versions as in `2.2.0-alpha01`.